# Rails: Need to scope by max version

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, scope

I have this problem, I've got database table that looks like this:

```
"63";"CLINICAL...";"Please...";Blah...;"2014-09-23 13:15:59";37;8
"64";"CLINICAL...";"Please...";Blah...;"2014-09-23 13:22:51";37;9
```

The values that matter are the second to last and last one.
As you can see, the second to last (abstract_category_numbers) are the same, but the last differs (version_numbers)

Here is the problem:
When I make a scope, it returns all of the records, which i need to focus on the one with the maximum version number.

In SQL i would do something like this:

```
'SELECT * FROM Category c WHERE 
  NOT EXISTS SELECT * FROM Category c1 
    WHERE c.version_number < c1.version_number 
      AND c.abstract_category_id = c1.abstract_category_id'
```

But i'm totally lost at Ruby, more specifically how to do this kind of select in the scope (I understand it should be a relation)

Thanks

Comment: Can you try this? `scope :at_last_version, lambda { group('categories.abstract_category_numbers').select('categories.*, MAX(categories.version_numbers)') }`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can create a scope to select the `category` with max `version_number` like this:

```
scope :with_max_version_number, -> {
  joins("JOIN ( SELECT abstract_category_id, max(version_number) AS max_version
                FROM categories
                GROUP BY abstract_category_id
              ) AS temp 
         ON temp.abstract_category_id = categories.abstract_category_id
         AND temp.max_version = categories.version_number"
       )
}
```

Basically, we will select the category with the `max_version` value on `temp` table in the subquery.

Btw, I expect the table name is `categories`, you may correct it. Then the final query will be:

```
Category.with_max_version_number
```

Comment: This has really been helpful, I did not know i could use it like this. Thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

Scopes are suppose to return an array of values even if there is only 1 record.

If you want to ALWAYS return 1 value, use a static method instead.

```
def self.max_abstract_category
  <your_scope>.max_by{ |obj| obj.version_number }
end
```

Comment: This would throw the following error: `undefined method 'max_by' for #<Class:xxxxxxxx>` since a scope is not the same thing as an array. Scopes are supposed to return an ActiveRecord::Association. 

As far as the max_by method call is concerned, it could be simplified as `max_by(&:version_number)`.

Comment: nope, that code is valid, my 2cents:
[2] pry(main)> Service.accepteds.max_by(&:id)

returns: #<Service:0x007efc8f72fcf8 etc, etc,

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question: you have a database table with a `version_number` column, which rails represents using an Active Record model--that I'll call `Category` because I don't know what you've called it--and you want to find the single `Category` record with the largest `version_number`?

```
Category.all.order(version_numbers: :DESC).limit(1).first
```

This query asks for all `Category` records ordered by `version_number` from highest to lowest and limits the request to one record (the first record, a.k.a the highest). Because the result of this request is an array containing one record, we call `.first` on the request to simply return the record.

As far as I'm aware, a scope is simply a named query (I don't actually use scopes). I think you can save this query as a scope by adding the following to your `Category` model. [This rails guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#scopes) explains more about Scopes.

```
scope :highest_version, -> { all.order(version_numbers: :DESC).limit(1).first }
```

Comment: You would use that scope by calling `Category.highest_version`

Comment: This would find only one. The problem was that there were more categories, each with different highest_version, and i needed each of the categories with the highest version for the category. Thank you anyway

Answer (score 0):

I `join` implementation with baby_squeel but for some reason it was very slow on mysql. So I ended up with something like:

```
scope :only_latest, -> do
  where(%{
    NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM Category c 
      WHERE categories.version_number < version_number 
      AND categories.abstract_category_id = abstract_category_id')
  }
end
```

I filed a BabySqueel [bug](https://github.com/rzane/baby_squeel/issues/123) as I spent a long time trying to do in a code proper way to no avail.